# Visual Studio Debugger and Windows 10

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I recently updated my system from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Before I did this, my Visual Studio C++ compiler (2013) and debugger was working fine but when I ran the debugger, I would occasionally get the following message:

The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remove computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remove computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

When I got the message, I would restart the debugger and the message would go away. After upgrading to Windows 10, every time I run the debugger, I get this message. Then the debugger does not run. So, I upgraded to Visual Studio C++ 2015 hoping it would fix the problem. It does not. I also use ZoneAlarm as my firewall. I thought that might be the problem. So I turned off ZoneAlarm but that did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing your intended setup, it is hard to tell why you are getting this message - i.e., are you trying to debug a process on a remote machine, or are you trying to use the Local Debugger?  Even using the Local Debugger can result in this message.  More information might help.  Microsoft has a list of reasons why one might get this error [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to debug a C++ program that I wrote and runs on my local machine. I am using the debugger that came with the Visual Stdio.

Comment: Along with disabling your firewall, have you tried disabling any antivirus software you have running?  Apparently VS uses the Remote Debugger to debug 64-bit applications, and it communicates using the local network.  Incidentally, I've used VS2013 on Windows 10 with none of the issues you've mentioned.

Comment: I disabled both my Firewall and antivirus program. However, that did not help.

Comment: I built a small five line C++ program in Visual Stdio and I was able to use the debugger on that. Once, I was able to get the debugger started an old project. Therefore it seems to work sometimes but most of the times it does not. Any additional thoughts?